# Why does background color only works in developer tools (toggle device toolbar)

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a linear gradient background for the top of a carousel in my theme.
This is the CSS code:

```css
 .carousel-item::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
  }
```

```html
 <div class="carousel-item"></div>
```

The style works well on firefox and edge. but doesn't work on chrome and opera, as you see

[image]

And there is one strange thing: when I use "toggle device toolbar" in developer tools, it works!

[image]

Where is the problem?!

Comment: your gradient syntax is correct. but I see that there is an error in `content` or before class

Comment: Your code hasn't any problem. check other things. try `hard refresh` in chrome to clear cash.

Comment: There seems to be no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct but few thing missing in your code. You haven't close **Curly brackets** `}`. You should add `left` or `right` `position` (i.e.: `left : 0;` or `right: 0;)`. That code should look like this.

```
.carousel-item{
    position: relative;
}
/* CSS3 syntax */
.carousel-item::before{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    content: "";
    height: 500px;/* Or 100% */
    left: 0; /* It's missing */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* If you face any issue in CSS3 syntax you can use CSS2 syntax
to support more older browser and all latest browser */
.carousel-item:before{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, rgba(145, 232, 66, 0) 100%);
    content: "";
    height: 500px;/* Or 100% */
    left: 0; /* It's missing */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

> If your `CSS` isn't update properly do your `browser` hard `refresh` or `clean` your `browser` `cache`.